# How to know what will happen concurrently in Go when dealing with 3rd party code

Tags: concurrency, go

Let's say I'm using a fictional package in my webserver called `github.com/john/jupiterDb` that I'm using to connect to my database hosted on Jupiter.

When someone makes a request to my server, I want to store the body of the request in my Jupiter DB. So I have some code like this:

```
http.HandleFunc("/SomeEvent", registerSomeEvent)
```

And in my `registerSomeEvent` handler I want to do this:

```
func registerSomeEvent(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    jupiterDb.Insert(r.Body) // Takes a while!
    fmt.FPrint(w, "Thanks!")
}
```

Now obviously I don't want to wait for the round trip to Jupiter to thank my user. So the obvious Go thing to do is to wrap that `Insert` call in a go routine.

But oftentimes creators of packages that do lengthy IO will use go routines in the package to ensure these functions return immediately and are non-blocking. Does this mean I need to check the source for every package I use to make sure I'm using concurrency correctly?

Should I wrap it in an extra go routine anyway or should I trust the maintainer has already done the work for me? This feels to make like I have less ability to treat a package as a black box, or am I missing something?

Comment: no sane library would silently background a call like `Insert` and return without an error, unless it _very_ explicitly documented why. Not to mention, you need to handle the error value in your code too.

Comment: The convention in Go is usually that "you just block" (mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/Kcccho0zGjo/lSF2wC-TdpoJ) and I think I've heard a Go team member, maybe Andrew Gerrand, say it too). If something is async, the documentation should cover that. As JimB points out, that's arguably the only sane way for a database Insert call to work in any language, since DBs have to guarantee your stuff has really been written at some point, and Insert (or a hypothetical Commit) are the most obvious points.

Comment: @twotwotwo If it blocks though, presumably my server will be unresponsive as I'm waiting for a reply from Jupiter. Or do you mean block in a goroutine?

Comment: @mattharrison, no your server will not be unresponsive because each web request is handled in a new goroutine.  This means only the current goroutine running the db call will block and all other requests will continue on their merry way.

Comment: @MattHarrison Most library calls block the currently-running goroutine--the current Web request, for example--just as most library calls block the current process or thread in other languages. Since the `go` statement will happily background any function call, it might be be more confusing than helpful if calls to library functions sometimes implicitly backgrounded work without telling you.

Comment: @RalphCaraveo but in the above example the DB call and the web request are in the same go routine are they not? So I would imagine the response would not be written until the DB operation is finished.

Comment: @MattHarrison I think you and Ralph are just talking differently about the same behavior. Ralph's saying the larger server process would respond to other requests while Insert runs (so in that sense it's not "unresponsive"). You're saying that the response to this request would come slowly if you didn't explicitly background the insert. Both statements are accurate.

Comment: @twotwotwo thanks for clearing that up. I suspected that but it's reassuring for you to confirm. So if my user wasn't interested in whether the data was inserted ok, it would be sensible I think to prefix the insert with `go` to background that call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just read the body and send it to a channel. A group of goroutines will be reading from the channel and send to jupiter the payload.

```
var reqPayloadChannel = make(chan string, 100)

func jupiter_worker() {
    for payload := range reqPayloadChannel {
        jupiterDb.Insert(payload) // Takes a while!
    }
}

func registerSomeEvent(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    reqPayloadChannel <- r.Body.ReadAll()
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Thanks!")
}
```

Next steps are to setup the working group and to handle the case when the jupiter channel is full due to very slow clients.